# Como fazer a divisão de uma variável pelos valores de um array no php

Tags: php, php-7

Quero pegar o valor de uma variável e fazer uma divisão pelo primeiro valor no array e o resultado dividir pelo valor seguinte até chegar a 1. Consegui até fazer a divisão, porém não é o resultado o  esperado. 
O valor para divisão é 60 e os valores para dividir está no array que é [5,4,3,2,1], Com isso ele dá o seguinte resultado [60,30,10,5,1]. O resultado que eu preciso seria esse [12,3,1] e quando o valor da divisão chegar no 1 ele encerrar a divisão.

Entendendo o resultado
60/5 = 12 
12/4 = 3 
3/3 = 1

O código que tentei fazer

```
function divisaoNoArray($x, $y)
{
        for($i=0; $i < count($x); $i++):
            $a[] = $i+1;
            rsort($a);
            array_splice($a, -1, 1, $y /= $a[$i]);
        endfor;
    return json_encode($a);
}

$array = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$num = 60;
echo divisaoNoArray($array, $num);


Resultado
[60,30,10,5,1]
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver essa questão? 
Agradeço desde já a todos

Comment: No resultado só números inteiros?

Comment: Olá colega, sim tem que ser numeros inteiros. Eu quero embutir em um script para trazer um resultado usando um método da matemática que é o Arranjo Simples e colocar todas as suas combinações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipo Assim?

```
function divisao($n, $a){
    for ($i=1; $n > 1; $i++) {
        $n = $n / $a[$i-1];
        echo "Divisão ".$i.": ".$n."<br>";
    }
}

divisao(60, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```